# Interactive pixel information with pcolormesh in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to use [mpldatacursor](https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor) with the python matplotlib function pcolormesh()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it it possible to use `mpldatacursor` with `pcolormesh`. However, since pcolormesh is defined by the edges of the grid, you need to click on the edges of the pixels for the cursor to appear.

Comment: Thank you, it does the job!

Comment: It does not work for me. I get the return message: AttributeError: 'QuadMesh' object has no attribute 'cvalues'. Any idea what this could mean?